# Finding Palindromes(perfect palindromes) in more than one protein sequences using perl

Tags: regex, algorithm, perl, bioinformatics, palindrome

I am a newbie in Perl (Regular Expressions). I need aa example on how to write a program for finding out palindromes (perfect) in more than one protein sequences (let it be 4 sequence with 200 amino acids in number, in a file) I have to filter out, the palindromes and the position of palindromes present in the sequences.

```
>TRE|Q47404|Q47404 (409 AA) Glycosyl transferase [Escherichia coli]
MIFDASLKKLRKLFVNPIGFFRDSWFFNSKNKAEELLSPLKIKSKNIFIVAHLGQLKKAE
LFIQKFSRRSNFLIVLATKKNTEMPRLILEQMNKKLFSSYKLLFIPTEPNTFSLKKVIWF
YNVYKYIVLNSKAKDAYFMSYAQHYAIFIWLFKKNNIRCSLIEEGTGTYKTEKKKPLVNI
NFYSWIINSIILFHYPDLKFENVYGTFPNLLKEKFDAKKIFEFKTIPLVKSSTRMDNLIH

>TRE|O06435|O06435 (492 AA) SynE [Neisseria meningitidis]
MLQKIRKALFHPKKFFQDSQWFATPLFSSFAPKSNLFIISTFAQLNQAHSLTKMQKLKNN
LLVILYTTQNMKMPKLIQKSVDKELFSVTYMFELPRKPGIVSPKKFLYIQRGYKKLLKTI
QPAHLYVMSFAGHYSSLLSLAKKMNITTHLVEEGTATYAPLLESFTYKPTKFEQRFVGNN
LHQKGYFDKFDILHVAFPEYAKKIFNANEYHRFFAHSGGISTSQSIAKIQDKYRISQNDY
IFVSQRYPVSDEVYYKTIVETLNQMSLRIEGKIFIKLHPKEMENKNIMSLFLNMVTINPR

>TRE|Q8VRL9|Q8VRL9 (492 AA) SiaD [Neisseria meningitidis]
MLQKIRKALFHPKKFFQDSQWFATPLFSSFAPKSNLFIISTFAQLNQAHSLTKMQKLKNN
LLVILYTTQNMKMPKLIQKSVDKELFSVTYMFELPRKPGIVSPKKFLYIQRGYKKLLKTI
QPAHLYVMSFAGHYSSLLSLAKKMNITTHLVEEGTATYAPLLESFTYKPTKFEQRFVGNN
LHQKGYFDKFDILHVAFPEYAKKIFNANEYHRFFAHSGGISTSQSIAKIQDKYRISQNDY
```

I need the output of perfect palindromes in this and also their positions.
I have gone through many articles, but couldn't get any better idea. Please suggest me some techniques and programs for this.

Comment: Read [perlretut - Recursive Patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Recursive-patterns).  It contains a regex example for finding palindromes.

Comment: You might get better answers if you provide some examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Please check, I have included example. !!

Comment: I have to check for each strings. I mean let the first string be x and the end be y so , x to y, x+1 to y, x+2 to y , x+3 to y and so on .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three regex features that are required for this challenge:

1. [perlretut - Recursive Patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Recursive-patterns) — To find palindromes
2. [perlretut - Positive Lookahead Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) — To find matches that overlap
3. [perlretut - Position Information](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Position-information) — To determine where the matches are in the string.

Putting these together gives this result:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pp = qr/(?: (\w) (?1) \g{-1} | \w? )/ix;

local $/ = '';

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($header, @lines) = split "\n";
    my $data = join '', @lines;

    print "$header\n$data\n";

    while ($data =~ /(?=($pp))/g) {
        print "$-[0] - $1\n" if length($1) > 2;
    }
}

__DATA__
>TRE|Q47404|Q47404 (409 AA) Glycosyl transferase [Escherichia coli]
MIFDASLKKLRKLFVNPIGFFRDSWFFNSKNKAEELLSPLKIKSKNIFIVAHLGQLKKAE
LFIQKFSRRSNFLIVLATKKNTEMPRLILEQMNKKLFSSYKLLFIPTEPNTFSLKKVIWF
YNVYKYIVLNSKAKDAYFMSYAQHYAIFIWLFKKNNIRCSLIEEGTGTYKTEKKKPLVNI
NFYSWIINSIILFHYPDLKFENVYGTFPNLLKEKFDAKKIFEFKTIPLVKSSTRMDNLIH

>TRE|O06435|O06435 (492 AA) SynE [Neisseria meningitidis]
MLQKIRKALFHPKKFFQDSQWFATPLFSSFAPKSNLFIISTFAQLNQAHSLTKMQKLKNN
LLVILYTTQNMKMPKLIQKSVDKELFSVTYMFELPRKPGIVSPKKFLYIQRGYKKLLKTI
QPAHLYVMSFAGHYSSLLSLAKKMNITTHLVEEGTATYAPLLESFTYKPTKFEQRFVGNN
LHQKGYFDKFDILHVAFPEYAKKIFNANEYHRFFAHSGGISTSQSIAKIQDKYRISQNDY
IFVSQRYPVSDEVYYKTIVETLNQMSLRIEGKIFIKLHPKEMENKNIMSLFLNMVTINPR

>TRE|Q8VRL9|Q8VRL9 (492 AA) SiaD [Neisseria meningitidis]
MLQKIRKALFHPKKFFQDSQWFATPLFSSFAPKSNLFIISTFAQLNQAHSLTKMQKLKNN
LLVILYTTQNMKMPKLIQKSVDKELFSVTYMFELPRKPGIVSPKKFLYIQRGYKKLLKTI
QPAHLYVMSFAGHYSSLLSLAKKMNITTHLVEEGTATYAPLLESFTYKPTKFEQRFVGNN
LHQKGYFDKFDILHVAFPEYAKKIFNANEYHRFFAHSGGISTSQSIAKIQDKYRISQNDY
```

Outputs:

```
>TRE|Q47404|Q47404 (409 AA) Glycosyl transferase [Escherichia coli]
MIFDASLKKLRKLFVNPIGFFRDSWFFNSKNKAEELLSPLKIKSKNIFIVAHLGQLKKAELFIQKFSRRSNFLIVLATKKNTEMPRLILEQMNKKLFSSYKLLFIPTEPNTFSLKKVIWFYNVYKYIVLNSKAKDAYFMSYAQHYAIFIWLFKKNNIRCSLIEEGTGTYKTEKKKPLVNINFYSWIINSIILFHYPDLKFENVYGTFPNLLKEKFDAKKIFEFKTIPLVKSSTRMDNLIH
6 - LKKL
29 - KNK
40 - KIK
42 - KSK
46 - IFI
66 - SRRS
86 - LIL
123 - YKY
131 - KAK
146 - IFI
164 - GTG
165 - TGT
172 - KKK
178 - NIN
211 - KEK
220 - FEF
>TRE|O06435|O06435 (492 AA) SynE [Neisseria meningitidis]
MLQKIRKALFHPKKFFQDSQWFATPLFSSFAPKSNLFIISTFAQLNQAHSLTKMQKLKNNLLVILYTTQNMKMPKLIQKSVDKELFSVTYMFELPRKPGIVSPKKFLYIQRGYKKLLKTIQPAHLYVMSFAGHYSSLLSLAKKMNITTHLVEEGTATYAPLLESFTYKPTKFEQRFVGNNLHQKGYFDKFDILHVAFPEYAKKIFNANEYHRFFAHSGGISTSQSIAKIQDKYRISQNDYIFVSQRYPVSDEVYYKTIVETLNQMSLRIEGKIFIKLHPKEMENKNIMSLFLNMVTINPR
26 - FSSF
55 - KLK
70 - MKM
114 - KLLK
135 - SLLS
137 - LSL
154 - TAT
205 - NAN
220 - STS
222 - SQS
271 - KIFIK
272 - IFI
280 - EME
283 - NKN
289 - LFL
>TRE|Q8VRL9|Q8VRL9 (492 AA) SiaD [Neisseria meningitidis]
MLQKIRKALFHPKKFFQDSQWFATPLFSSFAPKSNLFIISTFAQLNQAHSLTKMQKLKNNLLVILYTTQNMKMPKLIQKSVDKELFSVTYMFELPRKPGIVSPKKFLYIQRGYKKLLKTIQPAHLYVMSFAGHYSSLLSLAKKMNITTHLVEEGTATYAPLLESFTYKPTKFEQRFVGNNLHQKGYFDKFDILHVAFPEYAKKIFNANEYHRFFAHSGGISTSQSIAKIQDKYRISQNDY
26 - FSSF
55 - KLK
70 - MKM
114 - KLLK
135 - SLLS
137 - LSL
154 - TAT
205 - NAN
220 - STS
222 - SQS
```

Comment: Thanks Miller .. !! Do you have any blog or mail id to contact with u. Please share

Answer (score 1):

```
x="abaasdasdusduhfikliilkjhgjhgjhgh"

def checkpalindrome(str,i):
    if len(str)>2:
        rev=str[::-1]
        if rev==str:
            print i,":",str
i=0
for l in x:
    str=""
    k=i
    while k < len(x):
        str=str+x[k]
        checkpalindrome(str,i)
        k=k+1
    i=i+1
```

This creates all string combinations and passes it to palindrome function.